# Convert PHP Class in apache module

Tags: php, apache, php-extension

I have write a sophisticate system in php5 (many classes that use static method and include other files)

Now I want to distribuite that ant i would choose the module way, so i like to create a module like myFramework.so and include it in Apache (maybe) and after, when i write some php app, I'll use method and/or classes.

Now i write

```
<?php
include("myFramework.php");
myClass::callMymethod();
?>
```

The problem is I won't to share my source code and i don't think that obfuscation of code is the better way, so, i prefer to create a module compiled but i don't know :

1 - if is it possible
2 - if Yes, what is the ways
3 - other way

I whant to do that

```
<?php
myClass::callMymethod();
?>
```

and no use autoinclude, i wont to protect my code, i see that if I include curl module or mysql lib, I can use function for both, how I can create that with my framework?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot compile a PHP class into an Apache module. You may be able to rewrite it as a PHP extension, but that will effectively involve rebuilding your code from scratch in C -- you cannot simply convert PHP to an extension.

You will probably have better luck using a PHP encoder (e.g, Ioncube or Zend Guard) for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at hiphop:

- http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/
- https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/

Developed at Facebook, and project / code hosted on Github. Will convert code into C++, it depends on what you are trying to achieve, if it is protecting you intellectual property I would agree with duskwuff, Ioncube or ZG.

Worth noting is that once converted with hiphop, the result is not run as an Apache module but rather using a proprietary server also written at FB; well from what I have read so far.